# float right in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site where the content area is 960px wide. I have a slide out panel that i have coded into the site but when i float it right it only goes to the right of the 960px content area. How do i get it to the right hand side of the browser window outside of the content area. Sugestions...ideas?

This has been corrected

My new issue is that my slide out panel is behind my pages content when it slides out.

here is a link to the css for the slide out panel

[CSS](http://wordpress.pastebin.ca/2054068)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
.my-slide-panel {
    position:absolute;
    right:-200px; /* change 200 to whatever your actual panel size  */
    top:0;

}
```

Make sure that `.my-slide-panel` is in container that has `position` defined as *relative* or *absolute*.

Comment: that worked....now my issue is that it is behind my pages content...i tried using z-index: 1 but that didn't do it

Comment: You might need to use more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

use fixed or absolute position...

try

```
.class{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the floated element behind your content, try a higher Z-index (as mentioned above), but be aware that if the content is Flash, you need to add a parameter when calling the flash:

```
yourSWFObject.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
```

See http://www.ozzu.com/website-design-forum/placing-div-over-flash-t25572.html for a discussion on it.